# Django ORM multiple table data fetching

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am new to python and Django as well. I am trying to use Django ORM for fetching data from database but i am unable to do this. My database has three tables :USER,INVESTMENT_NAME and WALLET. The columns in user table are id(primary key) and name, columns in investment_name table is id(primary key) and name and the wallet table has user_id(foreign key references id in user table) , inv_id(foreign key references id in investment_name table) ,date,  quantity,amount and current price.
I am having trouble to fetch data which displays user name ,investment name,date,quantity,amount,current price using DJANGO ORM as i dont know how to do for multiple tables.

Any suggestions please.?

Comment: take a look at `select-related`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 0):

Do the Django ORM query on the Wallet table. Since there is a foreign key reference to both the other tables in this table, you can then access the entities using getters. Eg -

```
w = Wallet.objects.all()
w[0].user.name  # This is the username
w[0].investment.name  # This is the investment name
w[0].date  # This is the wallet date
```

Use the Django's official documentation for more understanding on orm queries and how you can optimize it.

Comment: i have a question. why to use w[0] as in what w[0] represents ?

Comment: The above query returns a queryset of wallet objects. For better understanding, I took the first element out of that and showed you how you can access the rest of the model attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use doulble underscore to get table's ForeignKey (One-To-Many) relationship fields and related_name (*field_name*_set by default) to access to Many-To-One (ForeignKey that references the table) objects. There are docs: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

It's also good for perfomance to use [select_related](http://Lookups%20that%20span%20relationships) and [prefetch_related](http://select_related).